# Need help for SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error

I got `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` error for this code:

```
print(\"Test set predictions:\\n {}\".format(y_pred))
```

Can anyone explain to me that error?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the escape characters aren't intended:

```py
print("Test set predictions:\n {}".format(y_pred))
```

Or even better using Python3.6+ f-Strings

```py
print(f"Test set predictions:\n {y_pred}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use \ at the start or end as it neglects the character after it.
the correct way for that line is

```
print("Test set predictions:\\n {}".format(y_pred))
```